# Decipher Wix Text

Tags: javascript, html, css

A fellow web designer had dragged all of the HTML/CSS/JS from a Wix website to our normal website.  Now the boss has asked me to do something, and I can't decipher this absolute brick of HTML.  There's a position issue that makes it so if I add any text it smushes it all together.

I can fix the position issue with just a quick fix in Firebug, but if I go to edit the HTML I have no clue what the hell is going on.

Is there a way to wade my way through this?

Some of the "fun" HTML:

```
<div class="s45_border" data-reactid=".0.$SITE_ROOT.$desktop_siteRoot.$PAGES_CONTAINER.1.1.$SITE_PAGES.$mainPage.1.$comp-ihwc6mj1.0"></div>
<div style="height: 100%; z-index: 0;" data-gallery-id="comp-ihwc6mj1" id="comp-ihwc6mj1itemsContainer" class="s45itemsContainer" data-reactid=".0.$SITE_ROOT.$desktop_siteRoot.$PAGES_CONTAINER.1.1.$SITE_PAGES.$mainPage.1.$comp-ihwc6mj1.1">
<div data-image-index="0" data-displayer-width="1250" data-displayer-height="875" data-displayer-uri="90619a_86ac8e3a77144c20ba0d06e5d2df93ed.png" data-height-diff="0" data-width-diff="0" data-bottom-gap="0" data-image-wrapper-right="0" data-image-wrapper-left="0" data-image-wrapper-top="0" data-image-wrapper-bottom="0" data-margin-to-container="0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: inherit; opacity: 1; height: 321px; width: 977px;" class="s45imageItem" data-state="notShowPanel desktopView  unselected clipImage transIn normal noLink" id="comp-ihwc6mj1dataItem-ihwccgkv0" data-reactid=".0.$SITE_ROOT.$desktop_siteRoot.$PAGES_CONTAINER.1.1.$SITE_PAGES.$mainPage.1.$comp-ihwc6mj1.1.$2dataItem-ihwccgkv"><p></p>
<div style="height: 321px; width: 977px; margin: 0px;" id="comp-ihwc6mj1dataItem-ihwccgkv0imageWrapper" class="s45imageItemimageWrapper" data-reactid=".0.$SITE_ROOT.$desktop_siteRoot.$PAGES_CONTAINER.1.1.$SITE_PAGES.$mainPage.1.$comp-ihwc6mj1.1.$2dataItem-ihwccgkv.0">
<div style="cursor:default;" id="comp-ihwc6mj1dataItem-ihwccgkv0zoom" class="s45imageItemzoom" data-reactid=".0.$SITE_ROOT.$desktop_siteRoot.$PAGES_CONTAINER.1.1.$SITE_PAGES.$mainPage.1.$comp-ihwc6mj1.1.$2dataItem-ihwccgkv.0.0">
<div style="width:977px;height:321px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;" id="comp-ihwc6mj1dataItem-ihwccgkv0image" class="s45imageItemimage" data-reactid=".0.$SITE_ROOT.$desktop_siteRoot.$PAGES_CONTAINER.1.1.$SITE_PAGES.$mainPage.1.$comp-ihwc6mj1.1.$2dataItem-ihwccgkv.0.0.0">
<div class="s45imageItemimagepreloader" id="comp-ihwc6mj1dataItem-ihwccgkv0imagepreloader" data-reactid=".0.$SITE_ROOT.$desktop_siteRoot.$PAGES_CONTAINER.1.1.$SITE_PAGES.$mainPage.1.$comp-ihwc6mj1.1.$2dataItem-ihwccgkv.0.0.0.0"></div>
<p><img src="http://truespeed.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/severroom.png" id="comp-ihwc6mj1dataItem-ihwccgkv0imageimage" alt="" style="width: 977px; height: 321px; object-fit: cover;" data-reactid=".0.$SITE_ROOT.$desktop_siteRoot.$PAGES_CONTAINER.1.1.$SITE_PAGES.$mainPage.1.$comp-ihwc6mj1.1.$2dataItem-ihwccgkv.0.0.0.$image"></p></div>
<p></p></div>
```

Comment: You should read the description for the "wix" tag. This wix tag is for the Windows Installer toolset that creates MSI files, not for "Wix" web sites.

Answer (score 0):

The funny looking things might come from "react" https://facebook.github.io/react/

You could look somewhere inside of the JavaScript files for the according  "react-templates" which are actually responsible for the markup if you want to change something there.

But if it is just positioning, shouldn't some CSS changes do it?

Have you tried rules using "!important"?

Comment: Yes, some CSS changes will do it; however, I can't figure out (of the possible 48) position: absolute; I need to change.  I'm just trying to decipher the code to figure out which of the possible options is the one I'm looking for.